# When i try to command through terminal 'php artisan serve' it gives Fatal error in ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, serve

Would you please help me to find out my installation problem of Laravel. I installed composer then installed laravel. When i try to run the project through **php artisan serve**, it gives following error.

```
Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel_project/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel_project/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel_project/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel_project/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I mention some things that the installed laravel folder contains totalling 120 items and total size 651kb. inside the projct directory, there is no folder named **vendor**. i'm using ubuntu 16.

Comment: Did you run `composer install` first? Installing composer installs the package manager. But composer install downloads application dependencies including the laravel project, and compiles them.

Comment: yes i runned composer install but still didn't work.

Comment: Make sure your composer is successfully updated. May be it is not, that's why autoload.php is not there, and ensure your path when you try to execute php artisan serve. @user7421798

Comment: i runned **sudo composer install**. now there is no error shown but home page is fully blank. there is no text named "LARAVEL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If vendor folder is present in your directory, try this command. It may help you.

```
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: So carry on your next job. it's my pleasure to help someone or when someone gets smile from others.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Gravy mentions in the comments, you need to run `composer install` in order to generate the `autoload.php` file.

Comment: i also installed composer to root of my project directory but still didn't create vendor folder and gets error

Comment: It's confirmed that your composer is not successfully install, otherwise vendor is there. Try to watch out composer install process.